# Tentando entender ponteiros em c/c++

Tags: c, c++, alocação

Oi pessoal sou novo no stack e é o seguinte:
estou estudando ponteiros e fiz o seguinte código:

```
typedef struct {
    char nom[256];
    int size;
    float value;
}tdados; // criando o tipo tdados com base na struct

// função que inicializa

tdados inicializa(tdados *dados) { // iremos apontar para uma variabvel
(*dados).size = -1;
}

tdados e_inicializa(tdados dados) { // por não apontar para o endereço dá erro
    dados.size = 2;
    // o erro é que em vez de ir por endereço fdaz um fetch da variavel que causa problemas
    // o programa nã realiza o fetch
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    tdados dados;
    tdados edados;
    inicializa(&dados);
    e_inicializa(edados);


    fprintf(stdout,"Inicialização correta\nTamanho:\t%i\n",dados.size);
    fprintf(stdout,"Inicialização errada\nTamanho:\t%i\n",edados.size);
    return 0;
}
```

Eu sei que no caso da função inicializa ela funciona porque uso o ponteiro da variável dados para poder trabalhar com esta e no momento da chamada passo o valor absoluto (&) contido no endereço, no segundo caso (função e_inicializa) apenas passo a variável de forma "simples". Eu sei que estou usando ponteiro mas gostaria da justificativa do porque um caso funciona e outro não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque quando você **não passa por ponteiro ou referência, passa como cópia**.

Ou seja, altera um novo objeto criado em um novo endereço.

Com esse exemplo, é mais fácil de ilustrar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char nom[256];
    int size;
    float value;
} tdados; // criando o tipo tdados com base na struct

// função que inicializa

tdados inicializa(tdados *dados)
{ // iremos apontar para uma variabvel
    (*dados).size = -1;
    printf("Inicializa objeto em: %p\n", dados);
}

tdados e_inicializa(tdados dados)
{ // por não apontar para o endereço dá erro
    dados.size = 2;
    printf("E_Inicializa objeto em: %p\n", &dados);
    // o erro é que em vez de ir por endereço fdaz um fetch da variavel que causa problemas
    // o programa nã realiza o fetch
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    tdados dados;
    tdados edados;
    printf("Objeto dados em: %p\n", &dados);
    printf("Objeto edados em: %p\n", &edados);

    inicializa(&dados);
    e_inicializa(edados);

    fprintf(stdout, "Inicialização correta\nTamanho:\t%i\n", dados.size);
    fprintf(stdout, "Inicialização errada\nTamanho:\t%i\n", edados.size);
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Objeto dados em: 0x7ffee5d479b0
Objeto edados em: 0x7ffee5d478a8
Inicializa objeto em: 0x7ffee5d479b0
E_Inicializa objeto em: 0x7ffee5d47560
Inicialização correta
Tamanho:        -1
Inicialização errada
Tamanho:        0
```

Note como o endereço em **"Inicializa objeto" é o mesmo do "Objeto dados"**, ou seja, você está lidando com o objeto naquele endereço de memória.

Answer (score -1):

Você está passando a `edados` na função, mas como não é por ponteiro o valor não permanece. O certo seria retornar na função.

```
edados = e_inicializa(edados);
```

e botar um return dentro de `e_inicializa`:

```
tdados e_inicializa(tdados dados) {
    dados.size = 2;
    return dados;
}
```

Além disso você declarou as funções como `tdados` sendo que elas não retornam nada.